# Easy but complicated var manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm new here and since I'm not really sure how to do this I'll just jump right into it. I'm trying to write some code that will check if a ID **already exists** before creating it. What I've manage to do is this:

```
var idNumber = 0;

var idFinal = row.id + idNumber;

var aa1 = 0;

function asdt() {
  if (idFinal === "undefined") {
  aa1 = "Success!";
} else {

}
};
```

I've created a **row** ID that always exists so I can add the **idNumber** and result in **row1, row2** and so on, since the only difference in these ID's will be the **ending number**. The problem I have now is that **idFinal** will return for ex. **row3 even though row3 doesn't exist**. What I need it to do is **return undefined** like it would if I would do **`var idFinal = row3.id;` and then call `idFinal`**, so I can use it in the function. Because I intend the function to increment `idNumber` till `idFinal = undefined` and then create that ID!

Thanks in anticipation guys, I really want to make this work...

Comment: where do you get `row` from?

Comment: So you are creating some elements with consecutive "row"+id and while creating some elements dynamically, you have to proceed with "row"+lastidused ?

Comment: from the HTML, its the first ID that will always be there and never chance, I just made it because if I did var idFinal = row.id + idNumber; it didn't work because the ID="row" did not exist so the + idNumber didn't execute further.

Comment: Something like that, what I want to do is **add ID's to all my newly created Div's**, but I want to check if the **ID already exists ** and if it does it should continue checking till = **undefined** and on **undefined** create that! I can do all of that but **I can't get a return on my idFinal that is undefined**.

Comment: So like I said, if I were to do **var test = row3.id;** and call test **it would return undefined** because **row3 does not exist in my HTML**, but the way I've written it it just returns a **string with row3** for some reason... So **it doesn't actually check if ID="row3" exists**

Comment: Why don't you find last div get ID and add 1 for new id?

Comment: Because **I really want to understand how I can use variables in combinations with other commands** so that I may use these things in other situations. But I would actually love to see what you said in code :)